# echo img with other folder

Tags: php, image, echo

```
echo "<img src="'admin/'.$value['searchresultimg'].">";
```

This is a code for my echo image this is the correct address but why i am getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''admin/'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in` i think my double quotes are ok here because i have single inside.I have search google for same problem but i didn't find any.i tried putting it in `""` but i didnt work.i have no more idea on this matter. Any suggestion here is appreciated.

`update`

my double qoutes is not `OK` escape double qoutes fixes the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<img src=\"admin/".$value['searchresultimg']."\">";
```

Comment: give a moment to upvote and by the way what is your clan i join your clan?

Comment: just tem up in programming . Would u?

Comment: email : aangkunaefi@kawandesign.com

Answer (score 0):

Escape double quotes using backslashes `\ \`.

```
echo "<img src=\"admin/" . $value['searchresultimg'] . "\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<img src=".'upload/'.$value['searchresultimg'].">";
```

I think You missed a dot (.)

Answer (score 0):

echo '< img src="upload/'.$value['searchresultimg'].'">';

This will work.